# How can I convert flux element to a key map mono

Tags: kotlin, reactor, rx-kotlin

So I have an object of contactId and I convert it to flux and then I query the contact details using each Id respectively and after that convert it to Mono using collectList method and map it to another object let's call it DomainContactDetails like this.

```kotlin
Flux.just(identifier.regContactId, identifier.billingContactId ,identifier.adminContactId, identifier.techContactId)
      .flatMap { resellerGetContact(it) }
      .collectList()
      .map { DomainContactDetails.fromList(it) }
      .toFuture()
```

Are there anyways to collect flux element into key map instead of list. for now I'm using index of list to indentify which data belongs to the property

```kotlin
data class DomainContactDetails(
  val registrantContact: ContactInfo,
  val billingContact: ContactInfo,
  val adminContact: ContactInfo,
  val techContact: ContactInfo
) {
  companion object {
    fun fromList(contacts: List<ContactInfo>) = DomainContactDetails(
      registrantContact = contacts[0],
      billingContact = contacts[1],
      adminContact = contacts[2],
      techContact = contacts[3]
    )
  }
}
```

I want it to be key map so it might be a bit better like this

```kotlin
fun fromKeyMap(contacts: Map<String, ContactInfo>) = DomainContactDetails(
  registrantContact = contacts["reg"],
  billingContact = contacts["bil"],
  adminContact = contacts["adm"],
  techContact = contacts["tec"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in your solution at all, but since you are asking about collecting to `Map` here is an answer. See `Flux.collect()` operator:

```
/**
 * Collect all elements emitted by this {@link Flux} into a container,
 * by applying a Java 8 Stream API {@link Collector}
 * The collected result will be emitted when this sequence completes.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/collectWithCollector.svg" alt="">
 *
 * @param collector the {@link Collector}
 * @param <A> The mutable accumulation type
 * @param <R> the container type
 *
 * <p><strong>Discard Support:</strong> This operator discards the intermediate container (see {@link Collector#supplier()} upon
 * cancellation, error or exception while applying the {@link Collector#finisher()}. Either the container type
 * is a {@link Collection} (in which case individual elements are discarded) or not (in which case the entire
 * container is discarded). In case the accumulator {@link BiConsumer} of the collector fails to accumulate
 * an element into the intermediate container, the container is discarded as above and the triggering element
 * is also discarded.
 *
 * @return a {@link Mono} of the collected container on complete
 *
 */
public final <R, A> Mono<R> collect(Collector<? super T, A, ? extends R> collector) {
```

So, probably you just need to utilize an existing `Collectors.toMap()` API.